# How to read PDF files with Node.js without using third-party library?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read the content of a PDF document using Node.js `fs.readFile` method, but I'm getting some weird characters in the response.

```
fs.readFile(directory + '/' + pdf, 'binary', (err, data) => {

    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to read PDF: ' + err);
    }

    console.log('PDF content:', data);

});
```

Is there a specific encoding type that could be used to return the text content of a PDF document without using a third party library?

Comment: The simple answer is you're not going to have fun writing your own parser for PDF files so the best option would be to just use a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PDF file is not plaintext.

If you want to read it, you might want to check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#File_structure